# php assign new value to variable if condition is met

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

What is a better way in the code below to add a new value to the variables `$timestop` and `$time_diff` if the condition is met?

```
//Calculates difference in time using 24h format

$timestart = strtotime("14:00:00");
$timestop = strtotime("07:00:00"); //if smaller value, it must end next day and meets the condition below

$time_diff = $timestop - $timestart; //elapsed time

if ($time_diff < 0 || $time_diff == 0) //if result is negative value, $timestop ends next day
{
   $timestop = strtotime( '+1 day' , strtotime("07:00:00") ); //+ 1 day changes timestamp
}

/* UPDATED */

$time_diff = $timestop - $timestart; //added again

echo $time_diff;
```

Comment: If the variable didn't update, the condition in the `if` statement was not met.

Comment: @EvanMulawski the condition is met, I make sure. You can see it in the code too

Comment: Okay, so if you add one day, the time is the same. Any time + 24 hrs is the same time.

Comment: before the if: 1339909200, after the if: 1339995600. of course it does update.

Comment: @EvanMulawski Why don't you put that into an answer?

Comment: @EvanMulawski I know it's the same time. Changing the time is not the goal of the code. I'm changing the timestamp.

Comment: Actually, since it returns a new UNIX timestamp, it would be different. It should be updating to the new value.

Comment: @EvanMulawski, yes that is what I'm trying to do. However the variable is not being updated.. I can;t figure out why :-/

Comment: gosh! it changes, as i wrote above. **you are doing it wrong.**

Comment: Covering all the bases, did you print out the value before and after the `if` statement to see the change (or absence of a change)?

Comment: Why don't you use `if ($time_diff <= 0)` instead of `if ($time_diff < 0 || $time_diff == 0)` ?

Comment: @DanLee sorry you are right, i was checking `$time_diff` for the change which i did not update. With the new code, I'm interested if there's a better way to do it

Comment: @EvanMulawski my mistake.. I was testing by checking another variable. I updated the post to a new question

Comment: Try using the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes. New fashioned way :)

Comment: @DanLee yes I wanted to but there's more code I didn't add that's hard to implement into. Maybe I'll post a question for it

Comment: Okay, but it's very easy actually! But what's your question now, I don't understand what's the real problem.

Comment: @DanLee I just asked if there's a better way to update the variables. I updated my code. What I'm doing is just setting the variables again.

Comment: Nah, overwriting variables in PHP is totally fine and daily routine. Better than creating a new variable for every single bit in your application.

Comment: @DanLee great, thanks! I'll vote if you put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, overwriting variables is no problem, and it's daily routine.
You are not even overwriting in any other type, you're just resetting to another integer value.

It's even better, because you don't waste any extra memory space (which of course is not high, but think of it in a big scale).